# Singleton gets recycled

Tags: java, android, singleton

I have a singleton in Android for data loaded from xml. It gets recycled from time to time and I don't understand why. Singleton should exist through the lifetime of app process by my knowledge. Here's my singleton:

```
public class DataLib {

    public static CategoryList categories = new CategoryList();
    public static RegionList regions = new RegionList();
    public static CompanyTypeList types = new CompanyTypeList();
    public static SearchData searchData = new SearchData();
    public static CompaniesList companies = new CompaniesList();

    private static RegionData currentRegion;

    private static final DataLib INSTANCE = new DataLib();

    protected DataLib() {
    }

    public static DataLib getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public static void loadData() {
        loadCategories();
        loadRegions();
        loadTypes();
    }

    /* ... some more static functions are here ...*/
}
```

As you can see it is not instantiated by any activity directly but rather by the process itself. The data are loaded by calling DataLib.loadData() when the application starts = activity which will end when the data are loaded.

I cannot tell for sure what triggers the recycling - sometimes app needs to stay in the background for longer time, sometimes it's in a few minutes. I am logging the pointer of the DataLib class so I can tell that it truly changed = got recycled.

Any ideas? Thanks.

**EDIT:** Answer is partially in marked answer + comments to it.

Comment: Why `CategoryList` are static and not just private properties of your singleton `DataLib` instance?

Comment: I want them to be public so they can be accessed from anywhere and static because I think I simply don't need the instance. I think that this will not make any difference. The problem is that the whole DataLib object gets recycled, not only the properties.

Comment: If you're going to have `static` attributes in a class, there's no need for a `Singleton` pattern usage, just write a `private` constructor in order to say other classes they can't create an instance of this class. By the way it looks right now, this class doesn't seem a right `Singleton` pattern implementation. Also, note that `categories` and the other attributes are not `final` so they are allowed to get a new value anytime in your application.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds right. I will need to change the class itself and the approach as such too. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It gets recycled from time to time and I don't understand why.

Android will terminate your process "from time to time".

> sometimes app needs to stay in the background for longer time, sometimes it's in a few minutes

The OS and the user can get rid of your process whenever they feel like it. Singletons and other static data members need to be caches for persistent data, loading that data using background threads and the like.

If there is particular work that you are doing in the background, you should be using a `Service` for that, to indicate to the OS that you are doing work in the background independent of any activities. That does not prevent Android from terminating your process (e.g., at user request), but it will make it a bit less likely to terminate your process on its own (i.e., the OS will tend to choose other processes).

Comment: But if the process stops (either by Android or by a user) the app will re-launch from the landing activity which will load the data to the singleton again. But my app is not re-launched but is simply brought to the front with the previously active activity.

Comment: @Speedy: "But if the process stops (either by Android or by a user) the app will re-launch from the landing activity which will load the data to the singleton again." -- I have no idea what "the landing activity" is. Your process could start up to view any activity, such as "the previously active activity", depending on what the user does to return to your app (e.g., Recent Tasks list).

Comment: Yes, this may be the problem with my understanding. I thought that when the process (app) is terminated then next time it will always start with activity which has set  "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" in manifest (in my case LandingActivity). If it can be re-launched (after terminating) to any activity, then I understand why I'm having this problem.

Comment: @Speedy: Yes, there are ways in which something other than your `LAUNCHER` activity can be the first one to start up when your process is created. Recent Tasks is the best example. You will need to be a bit more flexible with your singleton (e.g., adopt a lazy-load pattern).

Comment: Yes, this changes everything, I will need a new approach. Thank you very much. I'm also thinking about setting **clearTaskOnLaunch** to true on my LandingActivity so it will always be loaded when coming back to the app :)